# 2010 VW Stuck in Park

Tags: transmission, vw, automatic-transmission, parking

I have a 2010 VW Jetta Stuck in Park.  When I turn it on, press the brake, and press the shifter button it doesn't move.  How do I get it out of park?

The brake light and dash indicator do toggle (lights on / dash indicator goes off) when I press the brake, so it's not the brake sensor.

Comment: Help, i had the same issue. But the plastic piece was weddged and it broke off. So now there is no little piece to push in the pin to release the shifter from park. I have searched up and down and cannot find the part or where to find the replacement. Anyone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the centre console trim, surrounding the gearlever, you will find a a solonoid that engages a pin into the gearlever linkage. Release or remove this to release the gearlever. You will then need to determine the exact fault of this detent and repair it to ensure future safe starting. Possible faulty solonoid.

Comment: On mine after I popped up the shifter cover, there's a yellow plastic piece I just pushed down.  It cleared up a few weeks after manually working it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be as Allan stated with a bad solenoid, but could also be a mechanical problem with the shifter itself. If you are pressing the button (after pressing the brakes) to shift and it does not allow you to rotate the gear shifter from park, the rod from the button to the latching mechanism or the latching mechanism itself may be fouled. A fix could be as easy as lubricating the latching mechanism, or it might be as extensive as replacing the entire shifter assembly.

Answer (score 1):

We just worked on my friends 1999 VW Bettle today. It would not come out of park, what we had to do was remove the center console and at the rear of the shifter there is a solenoid.

If you look on the passengers side of the solenoid and take a screwdriver and push the solenoid to the drivers side then spray it with some WD40, then let out on the screwdriver, then you push the brake, problem solved. Hope this helps you all.